# Tableau Filter to Apply Before Color Dimension

Tags: filter, tableau-api

this should be a simple solution, but I attached some pictures to help explain.

I have a database of candidates who were spoken to at University campus career fairs. Each candidate has a rating (0-4) that the recruiter assigns the candidate based on their conversation.

I want a simple bar graph showing the number of records (candidates) spoken to at each university, and colors to show how many of each rating number there are.

I have:

```
Columns: CNT (Number of Records)
Rows: School Name
Color: Rating
```

The graph works perfectly before I apply any filters:

[image: Before Filter]

However, I want the dashboard only to display universities where 100+ candidates were spoken to. Essentially, I want to cut off the bottom universities from the display.

When I add a "number of records" filter to the worksheet, it only shows me universities with 100+ candidates **with the same rating.** Thus, instead of showing me the schools with 100+ candidates and their ratings based on color, it just shows me the  (very few) schools that have 100+ students with the same rating.

Graph after I apply the filter:

[image: After Filter]

How can I make sure the filter is being applied before the color dimension?

Thanks,

Andrew

Answer (score 1):

Create your Filter based on the University field, and use the condition tab to specify your criteria

Or use the top tab to limit the number of universities

Answer (score 1):

I would try making a calculated field as follows:

{Exclude [Recruiter Rating]: Countd[candidates id]}

Then drag that field onto the filter shelf and set to 100+.

Answer (score 0):

**Andrew Neeld**, you could easily achieve this with Level of Detail Expressions. Try creating this formula:

```
{ FIXED [School Name] : COUNT[(Recruit Name]) } >= 100
```

This will calculate total number of candidates per school no matter how you build your report and return TRUE/FALSE whether the value is larger than 100. If you then drag this field onto filter pane and simply select *TRUE*.

I'd maybe suggest replacing the hard-coded mean value with parameter. Here is the link to [LOD Overview](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_calculatedfields_lod_overview.html). And some [Jedi LOD examples](http://www.tableau.com/about/blog/2016/1/lods-fun-jedi-filters-48123). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

drag school name into filters, and use this formula in condition tab:

sum([Number of Records])>=100